# SQL Server : find recent consecutive records that are greater than 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I need to write a query that shows the result broken down by `FormID` that have a value greater than 5 based on the most recent `LogDate`.

Based on the most recent `LogDate`, if there was a value that was less than 5, it should display values from that point that are greater than 5 as the values under 5 is a 'reset' if you will.

I am essentially looking at recent consecutive `LogDate` records that are greater than 5.

Say we have the following  record set:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate    
--------------------------
Form2    6      10/12/19   
Form2    7      10/13/19   
Form1    8      10/12/19
Form1    12     10/12/19
Form1    3      10/14/19
Form1    8      10/15/19
Form1    6      10/21/19
```

The following would return the following (please note I like to show the row_num as well:

```
 FormID   Value  LogDate   row_num
 ----------------------------------
 Form2    6      10/12/19  1
 Form2    7      10/13/19  2
 Form1    8      10/15/19  1
 Form1    6      10/21/19  2
```

Note in the example above, since the following record had a recent value under 5 (value of 3), we need to get the records that are above 5.

Another example:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate     
Form1    8      10/15/19
Form1    3      10/21/19
```

RESULT: No result would be shown as there are in recent record that is greater than 5

Another example:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate    
Form2    4      10/12/19   
Form2    3      10/13/19   
Form1    16     10/12/19
Form1    3      10/12/19
Form1    3      10/14/19
Form1    8      10/15/19
Form1    12     10/21/19
```

Result here would be:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate   row_num
Form1    8      10/15/19  1
Form1    12     10/21/19  2
```

Another example:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate    
Form1    12      10/12/19   
Form2    13      10/13/19
```

Result:

```
FormID   Value  LogDate    row_num
Form1    12      10/12/19  1 
Form2    13      10/13/19  2
```

From my understanding, this can be done with the LAG function but not sure how to put it altogether.

We can do something like the following:

```
   DECLARE @mytable TABLE
   (
     FormID VARCHAR(50), 
     [Value] INT, 
     LogDate DATETIME
    )

    select t.*, 
        lag(value) over(partition by formid order by logdate) lag_value
    from @mytablet
```

But not sure how to pull it all together.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Otherwise, what research have you done, and what didn't you understand about it?

Comment: @Larnu Added info on what can be done with lag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can do this with window functions like this:

```
select 
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by formid order by logdate desc) rn,
        sum(case when value > 5 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by formid order by logdate desc) grp
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = grp
```

The idea is to compare the number of values above `5` to a row number, counting from the most recent value. Rows where the two values are equal can be retained.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it with sample data from example 1 but it did not return the correct result. It returned 6 results. It should have only returned 4 results. Note that I am looking for result set that are greater than 5 since the last time they were lower than 5 or if there are none previous lower than 5 then since we kept record.

Comment: @NatePet: there was a typo in the window `sum()` (`logdate` instead of `value`). Fixed

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution. I am still testing it out and I think I found where it does not work. Please allow me more time to test and I will followup. Thank you once again.

Comment: @NatePet: one potential problem is if you have duplicate `logdate`s for the same `formid`. It makes the sort non-deterministic. You need a set of columns that uniquely identify each row.

Comment: Yes, in my real life case it was a unique date stamp so worked out well. Thank you for all your assistance. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by formid order by logdate)
from t
where t.logdate > (select coalesce(max(t.logdate), '2000-01-01')
                   from t t2
                   where t2.formid = t.formid and t.value <= 5
                  );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by formid order by logdate)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when value <= 5 then logdate end) over (partition by formid) as logdate_5
      from t
     ) t
where logdate_5 is null or
      date > logdate_5
order by formid, logdate;
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like example 2 works but can you update it so it shows the row_num as well. Also for example 1, I could not get it to work. Can you substitute my table name (@mytable) in the query and I can try it again. When I tried it, it said the following: "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: Also in example 2, it was in the proper data order but should we not put the following to make it work in all cases: partition by formid order by logdate

Answer (score 1):

Find an indicative answer in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a146d2a350dd1a68b1806028c866bab2).

The `reset_calendar` is the dates that a reset happened and is used to filter out the data.

```
SELECT temp.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY temp.FormID ORDER BY temp.LogDate) AS Sequence
FROM (
  SELECT t.*
  FROM t
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FormID, MAX(LogDate) AS recent_reset 
    FROM t
    WHERE Value<6
    GROUP BY FormID) AS reset_calendar
  ON t.FormID = reset_calendar.FormID
  WHERE t.LogDate > reset_calendar.recent_reset OR reset_calendar.recent_reset IS NULL)temp
```